# How to send a file in the request body for GraphQL API and Spring-boot application using postman?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, postman, graphql-java

I am using graphQL for my APIs and now I need to receive a file in the request as a **multipart file**, so how to send that file using **Postman** to my controller?

```
@Data
public class FileDTO {
    private MultipartFile smsFile;
}
```

```
@Controller
public class SMSBulkController {
    @Autowired
    ParsingService parsingService;

    @MutationMapping
    public ApiResponse<String> uploadFile(@Argument FileDTO file) throws IOException {
        parsingService.upload(file);
        return ApiResponse.success("success");
    }
}
```

and this is my graphql file:

```
scalar Upload
input smsFileInput{
    smsFile: Upload
}
type Mutation{upload(file: smsFileInput):MutateApiResponse}
```